# ViewwithTag does not fetch cell label

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitableview

I am trying to display the cell label text using the tag name. In my mainstory board in the default cell, I have added a lable and added the tag name as 70. I am trying load that data using the below method . Nothing displays out. Please help me.

```
[Crop Cropname] is not empty, cell.textLabel.text = [crop cropName] works fine.I am just trying to format things.




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        // Configure the cell...

         Crop * crop = [filteredItemist objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",crop.cropId];

        UILabel *cropNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:70];
        cropNameLabel.text = [crop cropName];


        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: If you created cell in StoryBord then use that cell only.

Comment: There was a default cell that is created in the story board when i added a tableview controller. The cell works fine if I populate the data using cell.textLabel.text. viewwithtag doesnot make any change some how.

Comment: You are doing in wrong way. If you add TableView in xib it will come without having cell. So better create cell separately and add UILabel in that only then use that cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` meted, don't initialise again any cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the Cell Identifier of the cell you are using in the storyboard is using the "Cell" reuse identifier you are using to dequeue a cell.

What could be happening is that you are not actually getting a cell from the xib, because it doesn't have a Cell with that identifier, but then you handle a nil cell by creating a new cell:

```
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this new cell doesn't have the added label with a tag of 70 that you added in the storyboard...

Comment: By removing this code and adding the cell reusable identifier. I am able to get the entries now. But will removing this code cause any problem ??

Comment: According to the docs,

using the following method:      

tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forRowAtIndexPath: 

will always return a cell from the tableview, assuming you have set a cell in the storyboard with that identifier. If you do that, then removing that code will not cause any problems.

Comment: thanks a lot. how do i choose a cell on a different tableview controller. I get the error Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for controller. in this case

Comment: You can't use a cell from a different tableview controller directly. It belongs to the other tableView after all. You can however copy cells from one tableview to another from within the storyboard. Just a matter of copy & paste..